# Неправильно работает XML-десериализация (восстановление из файла) объекта

Tags: c#, unity3d, xml, сериализация

Я использую Unity 5.6.6f2

У меня есть 3 класса: **Нейрон, Нейронный слой и Нейросеть**. Там расставлены [XMLIgnore] атрибуты (для избежания цикличности) и **сериализация** объекта происходит **правильно**. Однако, **функция десериализации** работает неправильно и выдаёт один и тот же объект (где например объект.слои.количество = 5) при любой строке пути файла.

```
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Xml;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Xml.Serialization;

    [System.Serializable]
    public class NeuralNetwork
    {
        public List<NeuronsLayer> Layers { get; private set; }
        public float LearningRate { get; set; }

        private NeuralNetwork() { }

        public NeuralNetwork(int[] layersNeuronsCount, float learningRate = 0.1f)
        {
            Layers = new List<NeuronsLayer>();
            LearningRate = learningRate;

            // create layers
            for (int i = 0; i < layersNeuronsCount.Length; i++)
            {
                Layers.Add(new NeuronsLayer(layersNeuronsCount[i]));
            }

            // set next and previous layers
            for (int i = 0; i < layersNeuronsCount.Length; i++)
            {
                if (i < layersNeuronsCount.Length - 1)
                    Layers[i].NextLayer = Layers[i + 1];
                if (i > 0)
                    Layers[i].PreviousLayer = Layers[i - 1];
            }

            // set random weigths
            var random = new System.Random();
            foreach (var layer in Layers)
                foreach (var neuron in layer.Neurons)
                {
                    neuron.Weights = new List<float>();
                    if (layer.NextLayer != null)
                        for (int i = 0; i < layer.NextLayer.Neurons.Count; i++)
                            neuron.Weights.Add((float)random.NextDouble() - 0.5f);
                }
        }

        public void Training(float[] input, float[] correctOutput)
        {
            CalculateLayers(input);
            CalculateErrors(correctOutput);
            UpdateWeights();
        }

        public float[] GetOutputs(float[] input)
        {
            CalculateLayers(input);
            return Layers[Layers.Count - 1].Neurons.Select((neuron) => neuron.Value).ToArray();
        }

        public static NeuralNetwork LoadFrom(string fileName)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName)) throw new System.ArgumentException();

            try
            {
                XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
                xmlDocument.Load(fileName);
                string xmlString = xmlDocument.OuterXml;

                using (StringReader read = new StringReader(xmlString))
                {
                    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(NeuralNetwork));
                    using (XmlReader reader = new XmlTextReader(read))
                    {
                        var res =  (NeuralNetwork)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

                        // set next and previous layers
                        for (int i = 0; i < res.Layers.Count; i++)
                        {
                            if (i < res.Layers.Count - 1)
                                res.Layers[i].NextLayer = res.Layers[i + 1];
                            if (i > 0)
                                res.Layers[i].PreviousLayer = res.Layers[i - 1];
                        }

                        // set current layers
                        foreach (var layer in res.Layers)
                            foreach (var neuron in layer.Neurons)
                                neuron.CurrentLayer = layer;

                        return res;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }

        public void SaveTo(string fileName)
        {
            try
            {
                XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(NeuralNetwork));
                using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    serializer.Serialize(stream, this);
                    stream.Position = 0;
                    xmlDocument.Load(stream);
                    xmlDocument.Save(fileName);
                }
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }

        private void CalculateLayers(float[] input)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Layers[0].Neurons.Count; i++)
                Layers[0].Neurons[i].Value = input[i];

            for (int i = 1; i < Layers.Count; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < Layers[i].Neurons.Count; j++)
                {
                    Layers[i].Neurons[j].CalculateValue();
                }
        }

        private void CalculateErrors(float[] correctOutput)
        {
            var lastLayer = Layers[Layers.Count - 1];
            for (int i = 0; i < lastLayer.Neurons.Count; i++)
            {
                lastLayer.Neurons[i].Error = correctOutput[i] - lastLayer.Neurons[i].Value;
            }

            for (int i = Layers.Count - 2; i >= 0; i--)
                for (int j = 0; j < Layers[i].Neurons.Count; j++)
                    Layers[i].Neurons[j].CalculateError();
        }

        private void UpdateWeights()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Layers.Count - 1; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < Layers[i].Neurons.Count; j++)
                    Layers[i].Neurons[j].UpdateWeights(LearningRate);
        }
    }
```

Что не так?

Answer (score 0):

Оказалось всё очень просто: мой конструктор по умолчанию, который, как оказалось, использует десериализатор, передавал параметры в основной конструктор, чем "портил" десериализированый объект. **Я просто сделал конструктор по умолчанию абсолютно пустым и всё заработало!**

```c#
//code...

private NeuralNetwork() { }

//code...
```